# Autohotkey remap Apple Mac keyboard on Windows PC

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to configure an Apple Keyboard with numeric pad to work on a Windows notebook.

I found lots of example and scripts and I was able to remap <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and all the functions keys to volume controls, media controls, print screen, etc.

I still can't find a way to **move focus to next window** (from a program to another): on Windows, this is done by <kbd>LAtl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, on a Mac by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but I can't find the Autohotkey command to launch the "move focus to next window" action.

I tried with:

```
LWin & Tab::SendInput{Alt & Tab}
```

or

```
LWin & Tab::Send {Alt & Tab}
```

but it says that **`This line does not contain a recognized action`**.

According to the documentation, a proper syntax would be:

```
LWin & Tab::SendInput !{Tab}
```

but nothing happens.

Here is my script:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SendMode Input
F7::SendInput {Media_Prev}
F8::SendInput {Media_Play_Pause}
F9::SendInput {Media_Next}
F10::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
F11::SendInput {Volume_Down}
F12::SendInput {Volume_Up}
LCtrl::LWin
LWin::LCtrl
RWin::RCtrl
F13::SendInput {PrintScreen}
F14::SendInput {ScrollLock}
F15::SendInput {Pause}
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The [documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) is your friend. Your `Send` commands aren't using the correct syntax.

Comment: @MCL I even tried with " LWin & Tab::SendInput !{Tab} ", like the documentation suggests, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
LWin & Tab::AltTab
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. Nothing changes.

Comment: @tobia.zanarella Did you try this code as is, without anything else in your script?

Comment: Yes, I tried with an empty ahk file with only that line, nothing changed.

Comment: @MCL Thanks to your answer, I was also able to remap `RWin & BackSpace::Delete` and thus create mac-like delete. Thanks!